# Difference between "statt" and "anstelle"

Tags: vocabulary

What the difference of usage between the words *statt* and *anstelle*? Are they just synonyms?

Comment: Can you put a bit more context with example sentences please.

Comment: "statt" here is also just short for "anstatt", which should further show their similarity. Yes, they are entirely synonymous. As to the examples above, "Anstatt des Olivenöls" is also valid, whereas "Statt Olivenöl" is further shortened for "Anstatt von Olivenöl" which again also works as "Anstelle von Olivenöl".

Comment: Please write an answer. Don't answer on the comments.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Uh yes, it is not. I'm not sure why you're addressing this to me though, I never claimed it was. I repeat: "Statt Olivenöl" is short for "Anstatt _von_ Olivenöl", not "Anstatt des Olivenöls" which is indeed a different case.

Comment: @Cubic, I don't think so. Judicial "An Eides statt" shows a different syntax than a mere "anstatt + zu-infinitive/dass-satz". I think it's possible that "anstatt" is merely a backformation by analogy, and that a different reading of *an* than we have in mind has to be seen: e.g. "zu, towards, bei" or more likely "gegen" cp. "statthaft" (gültig?), "statt finden" (Geltung finden, passieren), on the one hand, and "sich anstellen, stell dich nicht an" (ohne "so, dumm" o.ä.?) also etwa im Sinne von *etwas anders, also falsch machen.*

Comment: Eine Morphem-Wurzel, die im Endeffekt auf \*n hinausläuft, mal abgesehen von schwankhaftem Vokalismus, muss sehr kritisch betrachtet werden. I mean cp En *instead* (not *on*). Thus cp. *für etwas einstehen*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is your language style and feeling = they are synonyms. Together with "anstatt".

Example <sup>thx to comments</sup>:

> Anstelle des Olivenöls nehme ich Rapsöl.

vs

> Statt des Olivenöls nehme ich einfach Rapsöl.

vs

> Anstatt des Olivenöls nehme ich einfach Rapsöl.

There is no difference in meaning in these three examples. In this short sentence I could even not say which I prefer and why. That comes usually with the characteristic style of the surrounding text.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good and thorough explanation here (in German): https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/statt-und-anstatt.
"Statt/anstatt" can be used meaning "and not"; in this usage "anstelle" sounds odd.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit what do you mean with "and not", possibly with some examples?